# Problems with Nav on Razor.NET

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I was trying to create a new project. I tried to put an image on navbar but it is just showed in Home page.

The image show the default icon when I change the page:
[image]

My paths, the image is in Logos folder

[image]

Comment: Put some sample code so we will be able to help you

Comment: @PEDRO HENRIQUE FERREIRA BENTO: Could you include part of the razor code, related to the image, please?